# Can't get value inside for loop

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
    for(var b=0;b<2;b++){
        var imgc = new Image();
        imgc.src = '../images/' + b + '.jpg';
        imgc.height = 200;
        divv.appendChild(imgc);
        alert(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[b].width);
    }
}
```

The image's size wont alert when the alert is inside the `for` loop. When I move the alert to onclick, it shows up. I hope you can help me.

Comment: could you provide more code?

Comment: Did you declare 'b' ?

Comment: i did. it just wont alert inside for loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question might be answered a hundred of times before.
You have to wait before the image is actually loaded.

After that you can alert the width of the image.
Therefore you have to use the `onload`-function of the image

```
window.onload = function(){
    for(b=0;b<2;b++){
        var imgc = new Image();


        // note the selfinvoking function which is immediately called with b as a parameter.
        // inside the function b is now a local variable and will not change even if the outer b does
        // you ofc can name the local b as you want
        imgc.onload = (function(b){

          return function(){

            alert(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[b].width)

          }

        })(b)

        imgc.src = '../images/' + b + '.jpg';
        imgc.height = 200;
        divv.appendChild(imgc);
    }
}
```

Even easier you just can get the width from the object you just created - so not neccessary to get the data from the dom:

```
window.onload = function(){
    for(b=0;b<2;b++){
        var imgc = new Image();

        // note the selfinvling function which is immediately called with b as a parameter.
        // inside the function b is now a local variable and will not change even if the outer b does
        // you ofc can name the local b as you want
        imgc.onload = (function(img){

          return function(){

            alert(img.width)

          }

        })(imgc)

        imgc.src = '../images/' + b + '.jpg';
        imgc.height = 200;
        divv.appendChild(imgc);
    }
}
```

Comment: using onload would only return the 2.jpg's size twice... :(

Comment: Nope - you just did it wrong. Have a look at scoping in js. The b variable is ofc 2 when the loop is finished so both executed onload functions will return the image at that index. You have to scope the b so its unique for that loop and will not change... well I will add it to the answer...

Comment: I actually liked this better except, it returns the value reversed. The value of 2.jpg alerts first then 1.jpg

Comment: It alerts the value in the order the images finished loading. So when you load 10 images the alerts will come randomly (depends on the file size actually)

Comment: So that does it. You helped me a lot and also I changed the right answer to yours :) Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Now im gonna assume that you want your images to load after a certain time interval because the function will load the last image immediately if you dont put an interval as it will be fast.  if you dont want the 2 second interval just change the '2000' to '0' in the code...hope it helps:

```
var imgc = new Image();
var b=0;
window.onload = function(){ 
var s=setInterval(imgloader,2000);
}

function imgloader()
{
imgc.src = '../images/' + b + '.jpg';
imgc.height = 200; 
div.appendChild(imgc);
alert(
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[b].width);
b++;
if(b==2){
 clearInterval(s);
}
}
```

Comment: this code almost did it. it just alert variable b from 0 to 2

Comment: Nevermind. I just changed b=2 to b>=2. This solves my problem. Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: I could have helped if you had posted the whole code

Comment: Ahh didnt see that...my approach was to make it b==2

Comment: Loading the images with interval in 2 seconds will not work for a slow internet connection. Also setting the interval to 0 will result in the same error. The right approach is img.onload as stated.

Comment: But for now we can assume that the user is doing it in a local filesysytem and speed doesnt really matter

Comment: No actually we can't assume that. It doesn't make the approach better either. It overcomplicates things which are easy to solve on a standard way. And if you finally want to port it to Web the timing strikes again